# What is the difference between static global and non-static global identifier in C++?

Tags: c++, static, global-variables, identifier

What is the difference between `static` global and non-`static` global identifier in C++?

Comment: "Static global" -- what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Andrzej a global with the `static` keyword prefixing the type. `static int x = 5;` at global scope for example.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Static limits the scope of the variable to the same **[translation unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c)**.
A **static global** variable has **internal linkage**.
A **non-static global** variable has **external linkage**.

**Good Read:**
[What is external linkage and internal linkage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage-in-c)

Comment: If a non-static global has external linkage, what's the use of `extern`?

Comment: @rubenvb: The answer to your Q is explained in detail in the link inline to answer.

Comment: @rubenvb `extern` means that it's a declaration and not a definition, like the prototype for a function.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: this is true only if there's no initializer nor function body and so on (§3.1/2). @rubenvb: In an anonymous namespace, names have internal linkage per default, but you can make them explicitly `extern` again.

Comment: @Downvoter: If there is any technical reasoning for the downvote please enlighten us all with that reason.

Answer (score 12):

A global `static` variable is only available in the *translation unit* (i.e. source file) the variable is in. A non-static global variable can be referenced from other source files.

Comment: More specifically: using `static` prevents the linker from exporting the symbol from that translation unit.

Answer (score 3):

Global Non static variables are accessable from other files whereas static global variables are not

Comment: Of course, they are "accessible" via pointers. They just "cannot be referred to by names from scopes of other translation units" (§3.5).

Comment: @DyP I think it's obvious that Rahul meant that variable isn't accessible by it's name.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know what the difference is, correct answer will probably be even more confusing to you. In short, `static`s of a class aren't realted to statics at file scope. Statics of a class are esentially identical to regular variables, but they will have to be referenced by prefixing them with class name. Statics at file scope are regular variables that are local to the file only. To understand what that means, try to add two variables with the same name into a single project. You will get linker errors because there are multiple identical symbols. By making symbols static you will avoid that problems and variable's name won't be accessible from outside the file.