# Why declaration by 'extern' doesn't work with static functions in C?

Tags: c, static, extern

Suppose the code:

```
extern int foo(void);

static int foo(void)
{
        return 0;
}
```

Try to compile with GCC

```
$ gcc -Wall -std=c99 1.c 
1.c:3:12: error: static declaration of ‘foo’ follows non-static declaration
1.c:1:12: note: previous declaration of ‘foo’ was here
1.c:3:12: warning: ‘foo’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
```

So, how can I *declare* static function?

Comment: "So, how can I declare static function?" `static int foo(void);`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> **Why declaration by `extern` doesn't work with `static` functions?**

Because `extern` indicates **external linkage** while `static` indicates **internal linkage**. Obviously, You cannot have both on same function.

In simple words, when you use `static` on the function you tell the compiler please limit the scope of this function only to this **[translation unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106149/what-is-a-translation-unit-in-c)** and do not allow anyone to access this from another translation unit.
while function declarations are `extern` by default, when you specify `extern` explicitly you tell the compiler, Please allow everyone from other translation units to access this function.
Well obviously the compiler cannot do both.

So make a choice, whether you want the function to be visible only in the translation unit or not.
If former make it `static` and forget `extern`. If latter just drop the `static`.

**Good Read:**
[What is external linkage and internal linkage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage-in-c)

Though above Q is for C++, most of what is discussed applies to C as well.

Comment: Why is the static declaration followed by non-static is allowed in your opinion?

Answer (score 4):

You declare it with `static`

```
static int foo(void);

static int foo(void)
{
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`extern` means the function is defined in a different translation unit (file).  `static` means it is only used in the translation unit in which it is defined.  The two are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score -1):

Is n't it that static can be resolved with extern(al) linkage like
File1.c

```
static int fx(void)
{
    return int;
}
```

File2.c

```
extern int fx(void);

/*call */
fx();
```

Comment: If static(s) are not found in symbol table they can be resolved by just putting extern in REDEFINITION. Linker will resolve it in most of the cases. Though the simple definition of static is that it has a internal linkage scope.