# Why am I getting linking errors even with header guards?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does this not prevent multiple function declarations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425262/why-does-this-not-prevent-multiple-function-declarations)

Global.h

```
#ifndef Global_h
#define Global_h

#include <iostream>

unsigned char exitStatus;

#endif
```

OutputHandler.h

```
#ifndef OutputHandler_h
#define OutputHandler_h

#include "Global.h"

class OutputHandler {
private:
    static bool instanceExists;
// more code  

#endif
```

Root.h

```
#ifndef Root_h
#define Root_h

// declarations

OutputHandler *output;

#endif
```

Root.cpp

```
#include "Root.h"
// gets instance of OutputHandler
// more code
```

I am getting errors regarding **exitStatus**, **static bool instanceExists**, and **static class output** being already defined by **Root.obj** in **OutputHandler.obj**. I assume the issue is with including the header file **OutputHandler.h** in both **Root.h** and **OutputHandler.cpp**. Anyone know how to fix this or how to better organize header files?

Comment: The answers to the Q explain why in detail. In short, You should not define objects in header file and then include that header in multiple TU's. It violates the ODR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because include guards only work at the translation unit level (you can, for this simple case, consider a single C file to be a translation unit).

That means a single C file, if it includes the header file twice, will not process it the second time due to the include guards.

However, if you include the header from two *different* C files, *each* of them will get a copy of the variables defined in that header.

Then, when you link them together, you get the duplicates.

The easiest way to get around this problem is to never define things in headers, only declare them.

So, in the header (eg, `xyzzy.h`), you have:

```
extern int xyzzy;  // declare but don't define.
```

and in all the C files that want to use that, put:

```
$include "xyzzy.h"
```

and, in *one* of those C files, also put:

```
int xyzzy;        // define it here, once.
```

You can think of declaration as a simple "I declare that this exists somewhere, just not here", while definition is "I an creating this here and now".

Answer (score 2):

Declare `extern usigned char exitStatus` in `Global.h` and define it in *one* implementation file.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is during the linking phase; include guards in the headers won't help you.

In C, there is the separate concepts of *declarations* and *definitions*.  Declarations are what are put into headers; they merely state that a particular variable exists.  The *definition* of a variable is where storage is actually allocated for it.

For example, in your `Global.h`, you have:

```
#ifndef Global_h
#define Global_h

#include <iostream>

usigned char exitStatus;

#endif
```

This is *defining* a variable called `exitStatus`, and the linker is complaining because any given variable should only be defined in one place in a program.  What you need to do is *declare* it in the header, and then *define* it in only one place in a source (*.cpp) file.  For example, your header should *declare* exitStatus with:

```
extern char exitStatus;
```

and in only one source file, *define* it with:

```
char exitStatus;
```

The situation is similar for `output` in `Root.h`, as well as any other place you should be declaring variables in the header file.

See also: http://www.cprogramming.com/declare_vs_define.html