# c++ Update static int

Tags: c++

i am trying to update static int

**test.h**

```
static int Delay = 0;
void UpdateDelay();
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"

void UpdateDelay(){
Delay = 500;
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
    #include "test.h"

    int main(){
    UpdateDelay();
    std::cout << Delay << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

output should be : 500
but it shows : 0

Thx

Comment: `static` in this context means internal linkage – each translation unit will get a _different_ `Delay`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A global variable declared as `static` has **[internal linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage-in-c)**. This means that each translation unit (i.e. `.cpp` file) gets a private copy of that variable.

Changes done to a private copy of one translation unit won't have any effect on private copies of the same variable held by different translation units.

If you want to share one global variable, provide *one* definition for it in a single translation unit, and let all other translation unit refer it through a *declaration* that specifies the `extern` keyword:

**test.h**

```
extern int Delay;
void UpdateDelay();
```

**test.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"

void UpdateDelay(){
    Delay = 500;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "test.h"

int Delay = 0; // Do not declare this as static, or you will give
               // internal linkage to this variable. That means it
               // won't be visible from other translation units.

int main(){
    UpdateDelay();
    std::cout << Delay << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you put `static int Delay` in the .h file then each .cpp file will have it's own unique instance.

You want to use extern.

test.h

```
extern int Delay;
void UpdateDelay();
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
int Delay = 0;

void UpdateDelay()
{
    Delay = 500;
}
```

Comment: You cannot use `static` to define `Delay`, or you will give it internal linkage and it won't be visible within `main.cpp`

Answer (score 0):

you can't declare `static int Delay` in your .h  what happens is per cpp is it makes their own version of "Delay"

what you want to do is in test.cpp declare static int Delay just above your UpdateDelay

Answer (score 0):

In this usage, the keyword `static` means that each cpp file has its own independent copy of a variable called `Delay`.  So the one which `UpdateDelay()` changes is not the one that `main()` prints.

If you want to use a single variable, make it `extern` instead: In the header file, put `extern int Delay;`. In one source file, put `int Delay = 0;`.