# When would I use const volatile, register volatile, static volatile in C++?

Tags: c++, static, constants, volatile

I am wondering about the different uses of the **volatile** keyword in combination with **register**, **const** and **static** keywords. I am not sure what are the effects, so I think:

```
register volatile int T=10;
```

Suggest the compiler to store T in a register and the value of T can be modified from somewhere outside (OS, hardware, another thread)

```
const volatile int T=10;
```

The program itself can not modify T, but T can be modified frow somewhere outside the code.

```
static volatile int T=10;
```

If T is a data member of a class it means that all the objects of the class have the same value for T and T can be modified from somewhere outside. If T is a global variable in a file, the source code in other files (that are part of the project) cannot access T, but T can be accessed from somewhere outside. If T is a local variable in a function,once it has been initialized remains in the memory until the end of the program and can be modified from somewhere outside.

Are my thoughts correct and can any experienced C++ developer give an example where the above maybe used in real-world applications or it is very rare?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
register volatile int T=10;
```

`volatile` qualifier means that the compiler cannot apply optimizations or reorder access to `T`, While `register` is a hint to the compiler that `T` will be heavily used. If address of `T` is taken, the hint is simply ignored by the compiler. Note that `register` is deprecated but still used.

Practical Usage:

I have never used it never felt the need for it and can't really think of any right now.

---

```
const volatile int T=10;
```

`const` qualifier means that the `T` cannot be modified through code. If you attempt to do so the compiler will provide a diagnostic. `volatile` still means the same as in case 1. The compiler cannot optimize or reorder access to `T`.

Practical Usage:

- Accessing shared memory in read-only mode.
- Accessing hardware registers in read-only mode.

---

```
static volatile int T=10;
```

`static` storage qualifier gives `T` static storage duration (C++11 §3.7) and [internal linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage-in-c), while `volatile` still governs the optimization and reordering.

Practical Usage:

- Same as `volatile` except that you need the object to have static storage duration and to be inaccessible from other translation units.

Comment: For the second one, are you sure you're talking about const-volatile *objects*, or const-volatile *references* (or pointers to const-volatile objects)? Because it doesn't seem like a const-volatile object could map to hardware...

Comment: @Mehrdad: I was referring to, pointer to const-volatile objects something like: `unsigned char const volatile *hd_addr;`

Comment: Yeah, your example shows `const volatile int T=10;` which is different. :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: ah okay, It is the example OP quoted. I was trying to use it as a placeholder for explanation and I added the examples later on so kinda missed it. Anyhow now that you pointed it out, its there in comments to see for those who deserve to see :)

Comment: @Mehrdad: a linker script can bind a symbol to a particular place in a memory map, so as long as the `const volatile int` is not also `static`, it could potentially map to hardware.  Linker tricks like this are best avoided because they're not very intuitive, but I've seen them before in low-level embedded stuff.

Comment: @Gary99 That link concerns `volatile`, which clearly does have a variety of real-world applications.  The context of your quotation was a comment on the usefulness of the specific combination of `register volatile`.