# const volatile char string not printing properly

Tags: c++, string, volatile

I have a very simple program which just outputs indefinitely a const pointer pointing to a const volatile char; it goes like this:

```
const volatile char* const str = "ABCDEFGHIJKL";

while(true) {
    cout << '\r' << str;
}
```

The problem is that when running this program, the output is 1. There is a way to get around this, which is outputting `const_cast<char*>(str)` instead of `str`.

But if I do `const_cast<volatile char*>(str)` the output is 1, just like before the cast, so I'm guessing the 1 output is caused by the `volatile` keyword, which is strange because I thought that volatile only makes the compiler avoid optimizations in that variable, which shouldn't change the value of it.

My question, therefore, is how in the world did that 1 came as the output.

NOTE:

I've tried compiling it with GCC in Ubuntu 16.04, and with MinGW in Windows 7, so the compiler is not the problem(I guess).

Comment: const and volatile? Does it make sense?

Comment: I didn't think so however there is a thread here about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259939/const-volatile-register-volatile-static-volatile-in-c

Comment: I'm just trying some process memory editing software and came accross this problem.

Comment: [Interesting](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c72b302c0552fe5)

Comment: `const` and `volatile` on a string literal I've never seen, but I have seen read-only hardware registers declared `const volatile`.

Comment: @user4581301 -- the const and volatile are **not** on the string literal. They're on the pointer.

Comment: @PeteBecker No, it's a const pointer pointing to a const volatile char.

Comment: @manni66 This replicates a variable which may be altered by other sources, but from the point of view of the program, it has a constant value and address.

Comment: @Garmekain - whoops, that was sloppy of me. But my main point was  that the const and volatile are not on the string literal

Comment: Yup. That's me being lazy.

Comment: By the way, the `const_cast` could be a really bad idea assuming the `volatile` is there for a reason. A safer way would be to manually copy the `const volatile` string into a temporary `char` array (possibly a `std::string`) before outputting it.

Comment: @manni66: Assume you have a `struct DeviceDescr` that contains a `char vendorName[16]` and instances of this struct are in device memory,  read-only outside of the device, so one might access them through a `const volatile struct DeviceDescr *d`. Now, `d->vendorName`'s type decays to `const volatile char *`. This may be slightly contrived (I'm not an embedded dev), but you get the idea.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You got nuked by [Implicit conversion Sequences (ICS)](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.best.ics). The C++ `std::ostream` facilities have no overloads for `volatile` types. ICS kicks in, and selects the overload for `bool` type (because pointer types, irrespective of cv qualifications are implicitly convertible to `bool`).

Hence you see `1`... Change your output to `std::boolalpha` and you should see `true` instead.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(){
    const volatile char* const str = "ABCDEFGHIJKL";
    std::cout << '\r' << str;
    std::cout << '\r' << std::boolalpha << str;
}
```

Prints:

```
1
true
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/866f8d0d31fb6bc3)

Comment: The conversion is pointer --> bool; null pointer is false, any other value is true.