# Lambda in header file error

Tags: c++, lambda

In one of my classes, I am trying to use `std::priority queue` with a specified lambda for comparison:

```
#pragma once
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

auto compare = [] (const int &a, const int &b) { return a > b; };
class foo
{
public:
    foo() {  };
    ~foo() {  };
    int bar();
private:
    std::priority_queue< int, std::vector<int>, decltype(compare)> pq;
};
```

My program compiles perfectly until I add a `.cpp` file to accompany the header:

```
#include "foo.h"

int foo::bar()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This time, my compiler generates an error:

```
>main.obj : error LNK2005: "class <lambda> compare" (?compare@@3V<lambda>@@A) already defined in foo.obj
```

Why can't I create a accompanying `.cpp` file if my header file contains a lambda?

Compiler: Visual Studio 2012

My `main.cpp`:

```
#include "foo.h"

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mark it `const`, that way it has internal linkage by default. Or better yet, make it a functor.

Comment: You're declaring two globals both named `compare` because `foo.h` is being included in two separate source files. I concur with Rapptz.

Comment: Don't use lambdas this way. They are meant to create small local functions, not generally used functions. This is less readable than a normal function.

Comment: I'm only using the lambda to initialize the `priority_queue`, but should I switch it to a functor anyways? By the way, thanks Rapptz

Comment: I'm assuming that you're just giving an example, and your lambda is more complicated.  Because right now it's the equivalent of `std::greater<int>`

Comment: Why you don't pass the comparer as a template parameter, and use the lambda as a default value directly?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As @Rapptz suggested,

```
const auto compare = [] (const int &a, const int &b) { return a > b; };
```

Solved the problem. Why?

[Internal vs External linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage-in-c). By default, `auto`, like `int` has external linkage. So just how:

```
int j = 5;
```

In `foo.h` that would later be included by `foo.cpp` throws a

> Error  2   error LNK2005: "int j" (?j@@3HA) already defined in Header.obj

(VS 2013)

However, `const` makes the linkage *internal* by default, which means it is only accessible in one translation unit, thereby avoiding the problem.

Comment: Have spent a while trying to get this - solved it in 2 seconds flat!

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to replicate this problem for some reason. I'm trying this on VS2010 though - not sure if that made a difference. In fact, I tried including your header in two source files and it compiles, links and runs fine.

That said, do you want to consider using `std::function`. That way you can define the lambda in the cpp code and it won't get defined multiple times for whatever reason. (BTW, where's `foo.obj` coming from? Do you have another source file that is including this header ?).

foo.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

typedef std::function<bool (int, int) > comptype;
//auto compare = [] (const int &a, const int &b) { return a > b; };
class foo
{
public:
    foo() {  };
    ~foo() {  };
    int bar();

private:
    std::priority_queue< int, std::vector<int>, comptype> pq;
};
```

Then later in the cpp include and define the lambda and when you create the `pq` pass it to the constructor.

foo.cpp:

```
auto compare = [] (const int &a, const int &b) { return a > b; };

foo::foo():pq(compare){}
```

This way you're deftly not defining the function multiple times.

Comment: Its a linker error, so `foo.obj` is just the file after compilation