# undefined reference to static member variable in a static member function

Tags: c++

Here is my header file:

```
class MapObject: public ScreenObject {
    static float xoffset, yoffset;
public:
    static float Getxoffset() {
        return xoffset;
    }

};

#endif // MAPOBJECT_H
```

However on the line return xoffset; I get the following error:
undefined reference to `MapObject::xoffset'
why?

Comment: You never defined `xoffset`, only declared it. Put this in a global scope of exactly one source file: `float MapObject::xoffset;`.

Comment: Did you define the statics `xoffset` and `yoffset` in your .cpp source file to give them proper linkage ? Remember, non-const statics have to be externally *defined* as well as declared in-class.

Comment: you need to the static variables it in the .cpp file: `float MapObject::xoffset`, etc. But are you sure you want to have those static?

Comment: @WhozCraig Is everything not declared in private?

Comment: interesting makes sense, thanks for the info. ill remove my comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put this in a source file (by the looks of it `MapObject.cpp`)

```
#include "MapObject.h"

float MapObject::xoffset = 0;
float MapObject::yoffset = 0;


//... the rest of your MapObject code here...
```

In C++ non-const `static` members must be both declared in the class definition and *defined* with global scope to properly give the linker something to reference.

Comment: What do you mean by "defined with external linkage" ?

Comment: @Mahesh See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage-in-c)

Comment: I understand the linkage concept. I didn't understand in the context of your sentence. I think you meant the definitions should go at global scope. Isn't it ?

Comment: @Mahesh +1 You're correct. Thank you for the correction. Updated accordingly (been a *long* day).

Answer (score 1):

You have to have something like this in your `MapObject.cpp`:

```
float MapObject::xoffset = 0.0f;
float MapObject::yoffset = 0.0f;
```

This way you **define** and **initialize** them.

Comment: I gave credit to @WhozCraig

Comment: thank you for your answer, however it should not be static float, just float

Comment: @user2673108 I'll correct it.