# C++: I can't understand how the 'extern' keyword works in my program

Tags: c++, extern

I'm trying to understand how exactly *extern* works in C++. There are many questions asked about this keyword on StackOverflow but none of them clarifies my problem:

**Situation 1**

`AuxSource.cpp`

```
int GlobalVar = 5;
```

`Source.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "AuxSource.cpp"


int main()
{
    std::cout << GlobalVar;
    return 0;
}
```

*ERROR: one or more multiply defined symbols found*

*ERROR: `int GlobalVar` already defined in AuxSource.obj*

// What the heck!? I defined it once!

**Situation 2**

`AuxSource.cpp`

```
int GlobalVar = 5;
```

`Source.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "AuxSource.cpp"

extern int GlobalVar; // added

int main()
{
    std::cout << GlobalVar;
    return 0;
}
```

*ERROR: one or more multiply defined symbols found*

*ERROR: `"int GlobalVar"` already defined in AuxSource.obj*

// Same errors.

**Situation 3**

`AuxSource.cpp`

```
int GlobalVar = 5;
```

`Source.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
// #include "AuxSource.cpp" - deleted

extern int GlobalVar;

int main()
{
    std::cout << GlobalVar;
    return 0;
}
```

// It works, but how is that possible?

Every tutorial out there uses the combination of including outer (non-main) file with some global variable and extern redeclaration + variable use in another module but it doesn't work for me. Either I still don't comprehend the concept of extern or something's wrong with my VS2013 (much less likely).

Comment: It's explained here also I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The include tells the compiler to include a copy of one file into another before compilation. And the linker only likes to have a symbol defined once. So this statement:

```
#include "AuxSource.cpp"
```

causes GlobalVar to be defined twice: once in AuxSource.cpp, and a 2nd time in the file that is *including* AuxSource.cpp (Source.cpp). So both AuxSource.cpp and Source.cpp have this same code: 
    int GlobalVar = 5;

That is why the linker tells you that the symbol GlobalVar is defined multiple times.

The usual pattern to use for having a global variable in one file that you need to use in another cpp file is to do this:

AuxSource.cpp:

```
int GlobalVar = 5;
```

AuxSource.h:

```
extern int GlobalVar;
```

Source.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "AuxSource.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << GlobalVar;
    return 0;
}
```

This way you can put #include "AuxSource.h" in many files and be able to use your one copy of GlobalVar that lives in AuxSource.cpp.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is this:

```
#include "AuxSource.cpp"
```

Normally, you do not include `*.cpp` files, but you include a corresponding `*.h` file. So you could have a header file `AuxSource.h` that contains:

```
extern int GlobalVar;
```

Then, you `#include "AuxSource.h"` in each of your source files, and so they each get an `extern` declaration of your global variable.

The *actual* definition of `int GlobalVar = 5;` would remain in `AuxSource.cpp` which is only compiled once.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't about `extern` more about linkage.

```
int GlobalVar = 5;
```

GlobalVar by default has external linkage. Try

```
const int GlobalVar = 5; //internal linkage
```

For more info see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage-in-c).

Comment: What if I want to change GlobalVar value in my `main()`?

Comment: Thanks for the link though. I think I get now why situations 1 & 2 are illegal.