# My non-member static function allows changing and creating of non static variables

Tags: c++

this is the code snippet

```
static chck()//tracking how many times main has been called
{
    static a=0;
    int y=0;//this is not supposed to work
    cout<<"Total time main has been called:  ";
    a++;
    return a;
}
```

our teacher told us that static functions can't change or create non static variables
but it works for me ,why?

Comment: `static` **member** functions cannot use/change non-static **data members** because that makes no sense. The function isn't called on any object to use the members of. This `static` just means the function has internal linkage. It's completely different.

Comment: what does a non member static function have linkage to?

Comment: Consider reading through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage-in-c

Answer (score 1):

In this case "y" is a stack variable which this function can access.

The theory is static member functions (static Methods in a class) cannot access non static member variables (non static variables in the class) as there is no object as "this" inside a static member function.

Answer (score 0):

`static` may well be the most overused keyword in c++.  Your first use of it refers to the linkage of `chck()`, i.e. it has internal linkage.  Your second use makes `a` `static` with respect to calls to `ckch()`, i.e. it's value will be preserved between calls.  You are think of `static` member functions of a `class` that can't access non-`static` data members, i.e. those data members that are created per object instance.