# using "extern" cannot find variables in other files when they are static or in namespaces

Tags: c++, extern

I listed my two questions below with C++ code. Thank you in advance.

**(1) Using "extern" fails to find outside static symbols. Why?**

*config.cpp*

```
static int config_id = 123;
```

*run.cpp*

```
extern int config_id;

void exec() {
  int id = config_id;  // "config_id" symbol not found!!! 
                       // It works when config_id in config.cpp is not static.
}
```

---

**(2) If `int config_id = 123` is in a namespace `namespace app`, how to correctly reference it?**

*config.cpp*

```
namespace app {
  int config_id = 123;
}
```

*run.cpp*

```
using namespace app;

extern int config_id;  // Fail to refer to the symbol in config.app. 
                       // How to fix?
```

Comment: (1) is pretty much the point of `static` (at file scope). What do you think `static` does?

Comment: The `static` declaration in `config.cpp` makes the variable file-local, so it can't be accessed from another file.

Comment: Also `extern` doesn't resolve using the the namespace defaults though, you have to be unambiguous: `extern int app::config_id;`

Answer (score 3):

`static` explicitly says that this `config_id` is only local to this file (translation unit to be precise), and is unrelated to any other variable with the same name. Your first example shows it doing its job.

In the second example, the variable `config_id` at global scope is different from the variable in namespace `app`.

You could do

```
namespace app {
  extern int config_id;
}
```

But you shouldn't be doing any of this - declare things in header files, define the in exactly one place, and it will all just work.

Comment: The "use header files" is pretty much the same conclusion as my answer, but unless the OP knows how to avoid using `static` and to make the declaration in the right namespace in the header file, it still won't help them. :-)

Comment: Are you sure we don't need `extern` there? I thought a bare `int config_id;` would constitute a *definition* and hence cause ODR trouble?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to enable `run.cpp` to refer to things defined in `config.cpp` is to create a `config.h` (or `config.hpp`) header file. That way, changes to `config.cpp` is easier to keep in sync, you only have to update `config.h`.

Anyway, to answer your questions:

1. In the first case, the `static` actually makes your variable invisible to other translation units. This is how `static` works for top-level variables.
2. In the second case, you still need a declaration that `config_id` is inside the `app` namespace:

   ```
   namespace app {
       extern int config_id;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

(1)
When you are using the `static` keyword in this context, you are declaring `config_id` to have "internal linkage", which means that it is only visible to it's compilation unit, config.cpp. If you want that variable to be visible in run.cpp, omit, the `static` keyword, as `config_id` will then have external linkage by default. See [What is external linkage and internal linkage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage-in-c).

(2)As Chris stated, `config_id` has been declared in the `app` namespace, so you will need to indicate so in "run.cpp"