# difference between extern "C" and simply extern

Tags: c++, c, extern-c

I have seen C/C++ code using extern "C" declared in function signatures and also while including a C header into a CPP file.

but some functions just declare extern before their signature(without the "C").

**QN1:**

are these both ways of defining functions have same effect or do they imply different things?

sorry if I am very silly but I am not able to find this difference through Google.

Eg:

```
extern int someFunction( void *ret_val);

extern "C" int someFunction( void *ret_val);
```

**QN2:**

if a function is declared with an extern in its signature, is it necessary for the corresponding header file to be included inside a extern "C" block?

As pointed by another user in comments, the marked duplicate does not fully satisfy the question here. I am editing so that in future others may not be mislead into a different question.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage

Comment: It seems that none of the answers in the "duplicate" question (and almost none to this question) describe what `extern` without "C" does (or how it differs from `extren "C"`). Here's the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) and here's a stackoveflow [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage-in-c) about it. Then there's another use with [templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template).

Comment: @user2079303: if you would have answered intead of a comment i would have accepted your answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MohamedIqzas I couldn't have answered since the question was already closed, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presence of `extern "C"` in a C++ file is a personal intent to disable **name-mangling** transformation that the C++ compiler does to the functions in that file. When there is no name-mangling, then a client C code can call these functions. This is done when you have a mixture of C/C++ code and you need to keep track of language-specific features. In a bit more geeky way, the C linkage becomes compatible in presence of a Cpp compiler.

The code could be anything from a variable/typedef to a full function/module declaration.

But if you do this:

```
extern char c; // same goes true for extern int foo()
```

it means that you are saying "I am using char c, which has a declaration external to this file". More like in another module somewhere in the search-path. This is implicitly global. In runtime, if c changes, the change is reflected everywhere. This is provided that your compiler directives such as -Iinclude_file_dirs -Ssource_file_dirs etc. are provided correctly (on GCC or g++). Using a powerful IDE such as Visual Studio 2010 or later, you can do these very easily.

"extern" is a linkage keyword. You can combine it with "C" for compiler-specific linkage directives.

Comment: @ha963ar: Thank You. Is the statement "This is implicitly global, static"  correct? I read that extern and static are different things in the links posted by user2079303 in question comments.

Comment: @MohamedIqzas      Thanks for pointing that out. It is definitely implicit Global (but not static). Static means the scope of the function/variable is as long as the programme. Corrected my answer now :)

Comment: "extern "C" simply means that the following block of code can be compiled either using C or Cpp compiler." - that's wrong.

Answer (score 7):

extern "C" disables name mangling. It will allow your C++ code to call functions from library compiled by C compiler

Answer (score 4):

```
extern "C" int someFunction( void *ret_val);
```

will make `someFunction` have C linkage.