# Why does value assignment exclude extern keyword and declare variable?

Tags: c++, extern

I understand why this won't link:

```
extern bool g_WinGame;
...
g_WinGame=true;
```

But why does this compile and link?

```
extern bool g_WinGame=false;
...
g_WinGame=true;
```

I'm using MSVC 2010

[edit] all is explained [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage-in-c)

Comment: The `extern` in the second example can be ignored. It is equivalent to `bool g_WinGame = true`

Comment: Well yeah, that's the question, why is it legal? As it seems legal to declare extern and then it isn't...

Comment: Because you can use extern to override internal linkage when using `const`. For example, in namespace scope `int const x = 5` has internal linkage but `extern int const x = 5` has external linkage.

Comment: That should have been the correct answer. Didn't know about internal/external linkage, a quick search provided me with all info needed. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't edit answers into the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
extern bool g_WinGame;
```

is a declaration.

```
extern bool g_WinGame=false;
```

is a definition. Here `extern` is redundant but legal.