# initialized and declared ‘extern’, why I'm seeing below warning?

Tags: c, extern

Why am I seeing the following warning: 
warning: ‘i’ initialized and declared ‘extern’

```
#include<stdio.h>
extern int i = 1;
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

main.c:4:12: warning: ‘i’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
extern int i = 1;

Comment: `extern` means that the variable is defined in another compilation unit that you're going to link with this.

Comment: Why are you using `extern` when that is not declared externally?

Comment: This is valid C (the `extern` is doing nothing), but rather pointless to write. It's definitely anti-idiomatic to write `extern` when you're providing a definition.

Comment: See C11 [§6.9.2 External object definitions ¶4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.2p4), which is a non-normative example that includes the line: `extern int i3 = 3;             // definition, external linkage` — which strongly suggests that the standard thinks it is OK, even though GCC does not.

Comment: Time to post a GCC bug?