# namespace noob questions: two cpp files sharing the same namespace have the same variable

Tags: c++, namespaces

namespace noob questions
I have two files in the same binary.

```
// class1.cpp
namespace A {
 const std::string k1 = "abc";
}
```

// class2.cpp

```
namespace A {
 const std::string k1 = "bcd";
}
```

They are not declared in header file.
Won't they collide?
I tried to compile and it can compile.
I should put them to unnamed namespace but even if I don't, it still seems to be able to compile.
Why is that

Edit: Those two files are actually included to build the same binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because `const` implies [internal linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage). You will get the expected error about duplicate symbols if you defined `A::k1` as non const.

Comment: tried to remove the const and bingo: compiles fails. 
thanks a lot!