# Why is C resetting my global array values to 0 when I use multiple files?

Tags: arrays, c

I've made a global variable for an array that's used in two files. We'll call them file1.c and file2.c, the variable is defined in a header file that both of them use, I'll call this file shared.h.

The variable is defined as `int items[100];` in shared.h.

The main is in file1.c, and it calls functions from file2.c, the main will first initialize all values in the array with -1.

```
for(i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
   items[i] = -1;
}
```

Now, when I call a function from file2.c that uses `items`, i've noticed that all values in the array are reset to 0 instead of -1.

My question is why is the global variable re-initializing?

Comment: Don't define the array in the `.h` file. Define in one, **and only one**, `.c` file, add `extern` to the **declaration** in the `.h` file. Better yet, do not use globals and pass a pointer around.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is external linkage and internal linkage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage)

Answer (score 1):

> why is the global variable re-initializing?

You have two different arrays with the same name. One with `-1`, the other with `0`.

```
//foobar.h
extern int array[100]; // <== declaration
```

---

```
//foo.c
#include "foobar.h"
int array[100]; // <=== definition
```

---

```
//bar.c
#include "foobar.h"
```