# AVR-GCC optimzed 'extern' global variable then error with 'undefined reference to ...'

Tags: c++, gcc, avr, avr-gcc

In short, a global const variable (array) defined in a .cpp file disappeared from the .o file, causing "undefined reference ... " error. The problem can be imperfectly solved by add 'volatile' to the definition of variable. It's useless to turn off compiler optimization or '-flto'.

Compiler: AVR-GCC 11.10 from https://github.com/ZakKemble/avr-gcc-build/releases.

Enviroment: PlatformIO.

OS: Windows 11 x64.

The definition is like:

```cpp
// file: oled_basic_init_sequence.cpp

#include <Arduino.h>

namespace  oled_basic {

    const uint8_t _init_sequence_for_ssd1316_4_wire_spi[25] PROGMEM = {
        0xae, /*display off*/
        0x00, /*set lower column address*/
        // ...
    };


    const uint8_t _init_sequence_for_ssd1306_2_wire_i2c[23] PROGMEM = {
        0xAE,
        0xD5,
        // ...
    };

}  // namespace oled_basic
```

With or without `PROGMEM` doesn't matter. In .h file:

```cpp
// file: oled_basic_init_sequence.h

#pragma once


#include <stdint.h>

namespace oled_basic {

    extern const uint8_t _init_sequence_for_ssd1316_4_wire_spi[25];

    extern const uint8_t _init_sequence_for_ssd1306_2_wire_i2c[23];

}  // namespace oled_basic
```

In main.cpp file:

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>


#include "oled_basic_init_sequence.h"


volatile uint8_t * test = 0;


void setup() {
    *test = oled_basic::_init_sequence_for_ssd1316_4_wire_spi[0];
    
    // this doesn't help
    *test = pgm_read_byte(&(oled_basic::_init_sequence_for_ssd1316_4_wire_spi[0]));
}

void loop() {

}
```

compilation failed with:

```bash
Building in release mode
Compiling .pio\build\ATmega128\src\oled_basic_init_sequence.cpp.o
Linking .pio\build\ATmega128\firmware.elf
c:/users/xxxxx/.platformio/packages/toolchain-atmelavr/bin/../lib/gcc/avr/11.1.0/../../../../avr/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\ccelvOYl.ltrans0.ltrans.o: in function `main':
<artificial>:(.text.startup+0x5a): undefined reference to `_ZN10oled_basic37_init_sequence_for_ssd1316_4_wire_spiE'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** [.pio\build\ATmega128\firmware.elf] Error 1
========================================================= [FAILED] Took 3.42 seconds =========================================================
```

Verbose build info:

```bash
avr-g++ -o .pio\build\ATmega128\firmware.elf -mmcu=atmega128 -Os -Wl,--gc-sections -flto -fuse-linker-plugin .pio\build\ATmega128\src\main.cpp.o .pio\build\ATmega128\src\oled_basic_font.cpp.o .pio\build\ATmega128\src\oled_basic_init_sequence.cpp.o -L.pio\build\ATmega128 -Wl,--start-group .pio\build\ATmega128\lib81f\libi2c.a .pio\build\ATmega128\lib685\libSPI.a .pio\build\ATmega128\libe29\libWire.a .pio\build\ATmega128\libFrameworkArduinoVariant.a .pio\build\ATmega128\libFrameworkArduino.a -lm -Wl,--end-group
```

Maybe I just made some low level syntax mistakes and still can't realize.

Comment: Don't put the definition in the header file. Declare it in the header file, define it in one `.cpp` file.

Comment: In fact, the problem can also be solved by just put the array to header file.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a good solution, but please provide an answer to your question. It's ok so answer your own question since it may help other people with similar issues in the future.

Comment: `uint8_t *ttest = 0` and `*test = ` - why are you assigning to  NULL?

Comment: @KamilCuk It's just "test". `test` is decorated with `volatile` so that compiler should generate code referencing that array.

Comment: it should be `test =` not `*test =`

Comment: `test` is a pointer to the memory-address 0 and you are trying to assign the value 0xAE to that address - not a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

##### Possible fix

Include `oled_basic_init_sequence.h` from `oled_basic_init_sequence.cpp`.

##### Explanation

```cpp
namespace  oled_basic {
    const uint8_t _init_sequence_for_ssd1316_4_wire_spi[25] = {
        0xae, /*display off*/
        0x00, /*set lower column address*/
        // ...
    };
}
```

Without the forward declaration of the variable with the `extern` keyword, this code defines `_init_sequence_for_ssd1316_4_wire_spi` with [internal linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage): it can't be used in other translation units.

With the forward declaration, the variable will be defined with external linkage.

```cpp
namespace  oled_basic {
    extern const uint8_t _init_sequence_for_ssd1316_4_wire_spi[25];

    const uint8_t _init_sequence_for_ssd1316_4_wire_spi[25] = {
        0xae, /*display off*/
        0x00, /*set lower column address*/
        // ...
    };
}
```

We can see on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/TPcTqcj71) that the compiler emits a global symbol for the variable in the second snippet, but not with the first snippet:

```
.global oled_basic::_init_sequence_for_ssd1316_4_wire_spi
        .section        .rodata
        .type   oled_basic::_init_sequence_for_ssd1316_4_wire_spi, @object
        .size   oled_basic::_init_sequence_for_ssd1316_4_wire_spi, 25
oled_basic::_init_sequence_for_ssd1316_4_wire_spi:
        .string "\256"
        .string ""
        .zero   22
```

Comment: wow, it works, thanks. I always remember that symbols are "public" by default. Maybe I should read some more basics, some time.