# unnamed namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces

What does it exactly mean when the Standard states

> $7.3.1.1/2 - "The use of the static
>   keyword is deprecated when declaring
>   variables in a namespace scope (see
>   annex D); the unnamed-namespace
>   provides a superior alternative."

I have referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions) but it does not cover what I am looking for.

Is there an example where the superiority is clearly demonstrated.

NB: I know about how unnamed namespaces can make extern variables visible in the translation unit and yet hide them from other translation units. But the point of this post is about 'static namespace scope' names (e.g global static variables)

Comment: I think the question you linked to pretty clearly demonstrates the advantages. What *are* you looking for?

Comment: @Andreas Brinck: Nope. I am looking at some code example or situation where static has a disadvantage as compared to unnamed namespace in the context of the quote from the Standard in OP

Comment: I think you are mis-interpreting the meaning of `global static variables`. The variables are not truly global (they can not be seen outside the translation unit. Note a global variable can be extern or static (not both).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### What does it exactly mean?

Technically *deprecated* means that a future standard may remove the feature.

In practice that isn't going to happen, because of the need to support old code.

So in practice it means, "strongly discouraged".

#### Example of superiority of unnamed namespace

An unnamed namespace is generally superior because what you have in that namespace can have external linkage.

In C++98 external linkage is necessary for things that can be template parameters, e.g., if you want to templatize on a `char const*`, it must be pointer to `char` that has external linkage.

```
#include <iostream>

// Compile with "-D LINKAGE=static" to see problem with "static"
#ifndef LINKAGE
#   define LINKAGE extern
#endif

template< char const* s >
void foo()
{
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

namespace {
    LINKAGE char const message[] = "Hello, world!";
}  // namespace anon

int main()
{
    foo<message>();
}
```

That said, it's a bit inconsistent that `static` isn't also deprecated for functions.

Answer (score 10):

This:

```
static int func_for_this_file_only() { ... }
```

is "as good as" this:

```
namespace { int func_for_this_file_only() { ... } }
```

but `static` can't be used for this:

```
namespace { class class_for_this_file_only { ... } }
```

Therefore, anonymous namespaces in C++ are more versatile and superior to `static`.

(I'm sure someone will argue with that conclusion, but as a C hacker I think the anonymous namespace solution is better.)

Comment: interesting. but the standard quote is about 'declaring variables in namespace scope'

Comment: For the class it helps to enforce the one-definition-rule if a class with the same name is created in a different translation unit with a different context.

Comment: @Chubsdad - see @Alf's answer below for what the standard means. IMHO it's a rather technical detail, but C++ has a lot of those (part of the reason I prefer C, but that's not something I should stir up). I think my example is a better argument for namespaces, but his example answers your question more specifically.

Answer (score 6):

Interestingly, ISO/IEC 14882:2011 (C++11) removed this language (in fact, it removes the whole paragraph §7.3.1.1/2). It also removes the mention of `static` from Annex D.

Thus, *using the storage class specifier `static` to give a name internal linkage still works (§3.5/3) and is no longer deprecated.*

Answer (score 2):

The goal is to define a symbol that exists only within your own translation unit. This can be "translation unit global" and may be a variable or a function.

This is commonly used in a class definition file as an alternative to private static class members as the static members have to be declared in the header, but a free-function does not have to be (unless it has to be a friend, which it virtual never actually needs to be, by the way).

The use of static would be:

```
static size_t BUFSIZE = 2048; // assume not const for this example
static int myCallback( void * ptr );
```

The use of an anonymous namespace is

```
namespace {

size_t BUFSIZE = 2048;
int myCallback( void * ptr );

}
```

The standard is saying that the second construct is preferred. We have found that sometimes it is advantageous still to use static in addition to the anonymous namespace to actually reduce the binary size.