# Namespace without a name in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unnamed/anonymous namespaces vs. static functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions)

I came across this code

```
namespace ABC {
namespace DEF {

namespace
{
```

I expected the namespace should be followed by some name, but it's not the case with this code.

Is this allowed in C++? What's the advantage for this unnamed namespace?

Comment: Dup of [Unnamed/anonymous namespaces vs. static functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions)

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate. This question asks "What is X?" The other question asks "When should we use X instead of Y?"

Answer (score 102, accepted):

It's called an unnamed namespace / anonymous namespace. It's use is to make functions/objects/etc accessible only within that file. It's almost the same as `static` in C.

Comment: Except that `namespace { void foo() { } }` in one file, `#include` it from another and try to call `foo();` works. It's not accessible only within that file. It means, that the stuff in it has internal linkage. I'd say that's a pretty critical oversight in the answer.