# Use of Unnamed namespace over static

Tags: c++, static, namespaces

Can I assume an object declared in unnamed namespace to be equivalent to as if were `static`?

```
namespace { int x; };//  #1

static int x; // #2
```

FWIK, In both cases, `x` will have static storage duration and internal linkage.
So does all the rules of an object declared as `static` applies to an object in unnamed namespace?

For example:

- What will be the order of construction and destruction? will it be same?
- Can I use `extern` keyword with `x` in unnamed namespace?

Comment: The specific questions at the end are not covered.

Comment: @aschepler: true, I've just looked into other question. voting to reopen this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of your questions are answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions) For the rest:

> What will be the order of construction and destruction? will it be same?

The order is unchanged from regular globals. So it isn't the same as static.

That being said, I *strongly* urge you to write code that does not care about the order. The less you rely on the specific order of initialization for any globals, the better.

> Can I use extern keyword with x in unnamed namespace?

No. In order to `extern` something, you have to be able to type its name. And the magic of the unnamed namespace is that you *can't* type its name. The name is assigned by the compiler. You don't know it. So if you attempt to `extern` it, you will instead be externing something else.

If you put an unnamed namespace in a header, every translation unit that includes it will get a different version of the variable. They'll all be `extern`, but they'll be talking about a *different* external variable.

Comment: Could you expand on the difference between a global (externalizable) variable and a file-static variable when it comes to the order of construction and destruction ? I thought (perhaps naively) that it was the same.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: If I recall correctly, file-static variables are all initialized before globals. I could be wrong though. Which is yet another reason to not rely on it.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I think you are confusing file-static with the zeroing of memory. Indeed initialization of globals happen in two phases. In a first phase, built-ins (and structs with no constructors) are initialized from *constants* and the rest (which require function execution) is zeroed; in a second phase, the functions are executed (including constructors). This is what guarantees that you can test a global pointer for nullity and set it on first (real) use.

Answer (score 2):

Both have internal linkage (the one in the unnamed namespace only in c++11) but the one in the unnamed namespace is  not a member of the global namespace. so for example you can put an x into the unnamed namespace *and* the global namespace and they will not conflict.