# Why are anonymous namespaces preferred to static globals?

Tags: c++, static, namespaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Superiority of unnamed namespace over static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422507/superiority-of-unnamed-namespace-over-static)
>   [Why unnamed namespace is a“ superior” alternative to static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977252/why-unnamed-namespace-is-a-superior-alternative-to-static)

I know know anonymous namespaces are "encouraged" over static globals which are more C like (and deprecated), etc etc, and I use them often myself. However, despite having read other posts and questions about this topic, I haven't really seen explicit reasons why an anonymous namespace is better than a set of simple static globals.

Is there a definite reason why I should stick to the former?

Comment: And see this as well : [Why unnamed namespace is a“ superior” alternative to static?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977252/why-unnamed-namespace-is-a-superior-alternative-to-static)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4977252/187543

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8236755/187543

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static variables at namespace scope are no longer deprecated.

There's no particular reason to prefer one over the other. A minor reason to prefer an unnamed namespace is that you can declare anything inside it, while only functions and variables can be static. A minor reason to prefer static declarations is that you don't have extra braces loitering around the declaration. Use whichever feels more harmonious to you.

Historical note: before C++11, there was one reason to prefer a namespace: for some bizarre reason, pointers to `static` objects or functions could not be used as template arguments, while pointers to non-`static` ones could. C++11 removes this restriction, along with the equally odd restrictions preventing, for example, local types being template arguments.

Comment: You can use the address of a function or global object as a template argument, but not if it is `static`. Go unnamed namespaces!

Comment: @curiousguy: that restriction has also been removed from C++11. Go `static`!