# Should I use unnamed namespaces in implementation files?

Tags: c++, file, namespaces, implementation

I have defined some functions (no classes involved here) in an external *.cpp file, and of course there is an appropriate *.h file.

Some of the functions in the *.cpp file are used *only* in that *.cpp file nowhere else. They are not even mentioned in the *.h file.

Should I put those functions into an unnamed namespace or may they live just next to the other functions? And if so, why should I need an unnamed namespace for them? I cannot see a problem, since those functions are not accessible from outside anyway.

Comment: Why not just make them `static`? (as in a static C function, not a static class method)

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin: Well in C++03 `static` was deprecated for that purpose. However, C++11 un-deprecates it. But `static` and being in the unnamed namespace mean different things. `static` will give it internal linkage, so the function can't be used for some purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.
Is any of those solutions, static or unanmed namespace, recommended or preferred?

Comment: @FredLarson The only reason it was un-deprecated in C++11 was because the committee felt that it wasn't realistic to get people to stop using it, not because they changed their minds about its use.

Answer (score 28):

If you want them to be truly private to that compilation unit, put them in an anonymous namespace.  If you don't then someone could declare those functions elsewhere and use them explicitly.

Take the following example:

`library.cpp`:

```
// a "private" function here, in that it is not declared anywhere
void f() {}

namespace
{
   // same as above, except within an anonymous namespace
   void g() {}
}
```

`client.cpp`:

```
void f();

int main()
{
   // Can call f(), it's been declared and is now effectively "public"
   f();

   // compilation error, this has no idea what g() is, it's not declared 
   // in any scope that can be resolved here
   g();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware of that "feature".

Comment: This is what `static` is for. Anonymous namespaces provide this feature for classes and structs.

Comment: Does the `static` keyword also protect against name collision with other functions that may exist in other parts of the code?  The unnamed namespace will.

Comment: How about if I put the declaration of g() + its namespace inside a header file (e.g. library.h) and include it in my client.cpp? Is the fine then?

Comment: I am sorry, but there is no compilation error in this code. https://godbolt.org/z/736cxjKxn .

Comment: @VictorYarema the anonymous namespace has to appear in a separate compilation unit

Comment: @Chad , right. Now I see. I initially didn't notice that the code sample you embedded in your answer is representing 2 separate files. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Chad , I slightly modified your answer in order to make it easier to see that it is about 2 different files.

Answer (score 4):

Your question can be split in two:

**1. "How can I hide global functions ?"**

One simple way to do that, is **NOT** to put the header of the function into the header file:

```
//============================
// Filename: "mylibrary.hpp"
//============================
// Description:
// Utility functions.
//============================
#ifndef MYLIBRARY_H_INCLUDED
#define MYLIBRARY_H_INCLUDED
//============================

namespace MyLibrary
{
    void DoSomething();
} // namespace MyLibrary

//============================
#endif // MYLIBRARY_H_INCLUDED
//============================
```

Full code file:

```
//============================
// Filename: "mylibrary.cpp"
//============================
// Description:
// Utility functions.
//============================
// self header include
#include "mylibrary.hpp"
//============================

namespace MyLibrary
{
    void DoSomethingBefore()
    {
      // ...
    }

    void DoSomethingAfter()
    {
      // ...
    }

    void DoSomethingConfirmed()
    {
      // ...
    }

    void DoSomething()
    {
      DoSomethingBefore();
      DoSomethingConfirmed();
      DoSomethingAfter();
    }
} // namespace MyLibrary

//============================
#endif // MYLIBRARY_H_INCLUDED
//============================
```

When this is compiled, you get a "mylibrary.o" or "mylibrary.obj" file. You may provide it, to other developers as: "mylibrary.hpp" plus "mylibrary.obj", but, without the "mylibrary.cpp" file. Most "plain c" / "c++" compilers can work this way.

There are other ways, read the next section.

**2. "Are anonymous namespaces, a good technique to hide global functions ?"**

The "Anonymous Namespaces" technique, is another way to hide global functions.

There is a similar question on:

[Unnamed/anonymous namespaces vs. static functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions)

But, personally, I don't recommend this technique, as the "favorite" answer.

Namespaces are one of those things, that I wish existed since the start of "pure c" or "c++". But, "anonymous namespaces" or "unnamed namespaces", seems weird to use.

Its like trying to hide something, and, later, forget, where do you store it.

**3 Additional suggestions**

(a) I suggest to use a single main **REQUIRED**, not optional, non-anonymous namespace per file. It may have nested, additional inner namespaces. Each main namespace, should have the same id. as the filename, but, without the file extension or file suffix.

(b) Avoid anonymous namespaces. Its like storing things in a warehouse, without an index.

(c) Use a file extension, or file prefix, in your header files, maybe ".h", or ".hpp", even if if its a c++ file. The standard says c++ shouldn't use an file extension or file suffix on "c++" files, but are difficult to identify or find on the filesystem.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

I guess if you don't want these functions to be seen from outside declare them as `static`.

Comment: *"... seen from outside..."* - From outside of what? The header? The translation unit?