# Why should we only use 'static' inside a class or a function (C++)?

Tags: c++, static, keyword, linkage

I was recently reading Stroustrups *The C++ Programming Language* and in the section about Linkage in chapter 9 I came across the following paragraph:

> "In C and older C++ programs, the keyword static is (confusingly) used 
>   to mean "use internal linkage". Don't use static except inside functions
>   and classes."

The problem is that reading further on, the author did not elaborate on why this is bad practice. I use static functions from time to time in my code usually for some simple calculation that is not needed outside the compilation unit, but I never realised this was frowned upon and it is not obvious to me why it is bad. Can anyone shed light on this for me please??

Comment: To owner of close-vote: how is this not constructive?

Comment: maybe this is some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage-in-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the idea is not to frown upon internal linkage, but to avoid confusion with the new meaning of `static`: `static` has way too many meanings (declaring stuff with internal linkage, defining local variables with static storage duration, marking non-instance members of classes), so avoiding one of the less intuitive ones is a good thing.

Because of this, the C++98 standard provides another way to declare stuff with internal linkage: [unnamed namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions), and deprecates `static` "when declaring objects in a namespace scope".

The C++11 standard removed this deprecation (and also changed somehow the semantic of unnamed namespaces, not really requiring internal linkage), so it's now really a matter of style.

Comment: Unnamed namespaces do _not_ make their contents have internal linkage.  They place it in a namespace which can't be named outside of the translation unit, but the linkage is still external, which makes a difference for templates.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Does it still make a difference for templates, or are you referring to the pre-2011 language?

Comment: @JamesKanze: what difference does it make for templates?

Answer (score 4):

Because in C++ anonymous namespaces should be preferred, which basically offer the same functionality.

I think `static` in this context is frowned upon because of the double meanings, and the fact that the two meanings are quite opposite - if inside a `class` or a `struct` it represents a global state, whereas outside it gives internal linkeage and provides a copy of a variable or method to each translation unit.

Moreso, `static` can only apply to functions and variables, whereas inside an anonymous namespace you can have type declarations.

```
namespace  //OK
{
    class X {};
}

static class X //syntactically correct, but does nothing
{
};
```

Note that the standard deems the use of `static` to specify linkeage as *deprecated*.

Comment: There's also the fact that you cannot use `static` objects or functions to instantiate a template.  (And there's the somewhat contradictory fact that a `const` variable at namespace scope is `static` by default.)

Comment: C++11 removed the deprecation, and also the silly restriction on template arguments. There's no longer any particular reason to prefer one over the other.