# Overload cout results in duplicate definition

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

I'm trying to overload the `<<` operator on the `ostream` - class?

For some reason I'm overloading it twice, I can't seem to figure out why cause i have `#ifndef` in my header file.

**matrix.h**

```
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class matrix {
    int x, y;
    public:
        matrix(int a, int b);
        matrix& operator* (matrix B);

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const matrix& A);
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const matrix& A)
{
    os << "Matrix.....";
    return os;
}

#endif
```

**matrix.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "matrix.h"

matrix::matrix(int a, int b) {

}
matrix& matrix::operator* (matrix B) {

}
```

and **main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "matrix.h"

using namespace std;

int main () {
    matrix a(6, 6), b(6, 6);

    cout << a;

    return 0;
}
```

I am building like this:

```
$ cat build.sh 
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ -c matrix.cpp

g++ -g -o main main.o matrix.o
```

The build error I am getting is:

```
$bash build.sh 
ld: duplicate symbol operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, matrix const&)in matrix.o and main.o for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Think this is strait forward but I can't seem to find the solution.

Thanks for your time.

---

**g++ -v**

```
$g++ -v
...skipped 4 lines...
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are defining a function with external linkage and including it in two compilation units.

I would advocate just adding an `inline` keyword to your function definition, or moving the function definition inside the class.

#### What does this do?

By adding a non-`static` free function like your `operator<<` you define a function with external linkage, which means that it causes an entry in the generated object files' symbol tables.

If the function is `inline` or `template`, the compiler/linker must handle this e.g. by simply picking an arbitrary one. (This is OK, because the [ODR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) causes them to be equivalent.)

If, however this is not the case (as in your example), this causes a linker error, since the linker does not know which one you meant.

You could also (or even additionally) declare your function to be `static`, which would cause it to lose external linkage (gaining internal linkage instead), which is just a fancy way of saying that it does not generate a symbol table entry. This will cause this function to be compiled into a new version for every compilation unit that includes your header, and is therefore inferior to the other solutions.

#### But the define guard?

Only prevents the function to be defined multiple times *in one compilation unit*.

#### OK, list all my options!

First, you could utilize a property of friend functions and define it in the class (which effectively causes it to gain the `inline` keyword as defined in C++ 11.3/7):

```
class matrix {
    int x, y;
public:
    matrix(int a, int b);
    matrix& operator* (matrix B);

    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const matrix& A)
    {
        os << "Matrix.....";
        return os;
    }
};
```

Alternatively, you could cause it to be an `inline` function by adding `inline` in front of it.

You may sometimes see both of these techniques combined: A friend function that is defined inside a class and also annotated with `inline`. The `inline` is completely superfluous in that case and does not change anything.

You may also cause it to gain internal linkage by either adding the `static` keyword to it, or wrapping it inside an [unnamed namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions). While this would solve the problem, it will cause unnecessary bloat, since every compilation unit that includes this function will have its very own internal copy. Technically internal linkage can be combined with `inline`.

Trying to make a template function out of this, while technically possible, is a lot of work and does not really gain you anything above the other solutions. It *would* solve your problem, though, leading to a variant very akin to the `inline` version.

As a last option, you can move the function definition into a single compilation unit (read: .cpp file). The matrix.cpp file is certainly volunteering, since it holds function relating to your `matrix` class anyway.

Comment: The other alternatives are to move the definition inside the class definition, or into a source file.

Comment: `static` is probably a bad idea: the program will probably be bloated with multiple copies, and you might get obscure bugs if there are any static variables, or if anything depends on the address of the function.

Comment: Given the function's triviality, `inline` would be preferred to moving it into a source file.

Comment: @MikeSeymour `static` and unnamed namespaces were primarily added to explain the problem that causes the error.

Comment: @dionadar: No they weren't. They were added to allow you to declare a name within one translation unit without clashing with the same name declared (for a different purpose) in other translation units. `inline` was added for this situation, to allow you to define the same function in multiple translation units *without* duplicating the function when linking.

Comment: I was talking about my answer, not the reasoning behind internal linkage in general.

Comment: @dionadar: Sorry, I misunderstood. Either way, the answer reads to me as if it's suggesting `static` as a way to fix the problem, which would be bad advice.

Comment: I made it a bit more explicit, to ensure that it is clear that `static` although a possible fix for the problem is not the best solution.