# Is there any diference between defining static function inside anonymous namespace and outside?

Tags: c++

In C++, I know that if I declare a function with static, it names will only exist to the compilation unit where it is declared / defined:

```
static void MyFunction() {...}
```

Also, if I declare my function inside an anonymous namespace, its name will only exist in the local compilation unit:

```
namespace
{
    void MyFunction() {...}
}
```

Also, I can use static inside the anonymous namespace:

```
namespace
{
    static void MyFunction() {...}
}
```

Is there any difference between those definitions?

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions

Comment: @catscradle almost the same, but do not discuss static usage inside the anonymous.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference.

First, let's be precise, even to the point of being pedantic:
the names exist everywhere.  The distinction is:

- If a symbol is declared `static` (at namespace scope), it has
  internal linkage, which means that the same name in a different
  translation unit refers to a different entity.
- An unnamed namespace generates a namespace whose name is
  unique to the translation unit.  The symbol still has external
  linkage (provided it is not static), but there's no way you can
  name it in another translation unit.

The main difference involves templates.  At least until C++11
(and maybe still, I haven't checked), any entity used to
instantiate a template must have external linkage.  So you could
not instantiate a template on something declared static, or
which implicitly had internal linkage.

Comment: Yes, C++11 erased the requirement about needing external linkage for templates.  Which is helpful, since I think the type of a lambda expression has no linkage.

Comment: @aschepler It's helpful even without lambda, but of course, lambda opens a whole new vista of possibilities.