# Use of namespace in C++?

Tags: c++, namespaces

```
#include "d3dApp.h"
#include <WindowsX.h>
#include <sstream>

namespace
{
    // This is just used to forward Windows messages from a global window
    // procedure to our member function window procedure because we cannot
    // assign a member function to WNDCLASS::lpfnWndProc.
    D3DApp* gd3dApp = 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK
MainWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // Forward hwnd on because we can get messages (e.g., WM_CREATE)
    // before CreateWindow returns, and thus before mhMainWnd is valid.
    return gd3dApp->MsgProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

I am curious about this use of namespace in C++. I started reading the documentation on namespace and I saw a lot of examples calling a name for the namespace like "namespace first" but none without anything after the namespace declaration like this one.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: This is an unnamed namespace http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions

Comment: It's an anonymous namespace I think. I remember someone telling me the above is the C++ way to have non-external-linkage of global variables (whereas in C you declare them `static`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an anonymous or unnamed namespace.  Items in the namespace (just the `gd3dApp` in this example) are visible within a translation unit, but cannot be referred to externally because there is no name to qualify them with.

Note: this does *not* prevent external linkage.  Take a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yct4x9k5(v=vs.80).aspx.

> Although entities in an unnamed namespace might have external linkage, they are effectively qualified by a name unique to their translation unit and therefore can never be seen from any other translation unit.

This technique is slightly superior to `static` because it also works for `typedef`s (which can't be declared `static`).