# C++11 Namespace or Class with Private Variables

Tags: c++11

I know that namespace are preferred in C++ if you want to define static functions, but what to do when you have functions which access other functions but the other functions should be private and not be accessible by others. How to declare/define it ? Wouldn't it be much simple to use classes ? Or do I have to still use namespaces ?

Like this:

```
class Test1
{
public:
    static void Start()
    {
        if(1) // Some checks...
        {
            ProcessStart();
        }
    }

private:
    static void ProcessStart()
    {
        if(!Initialized)
        {
            //Initialize
        }

        // Do other stuff
    }

    static bool Initialized;
};

bool Test1::Initialized = false;
```

Comment: If the functions need to be defined right in .h you may use a namespace with a special name within a "public" namespace. Usually that namespace is named `detail`. Take a look into libstdc++ or boost headers to get the idea in all gory details

Comment: Actually, the deprecation of `static` for TU-local symbols was taken back in C++11.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to expose private details in the public API:

**foo.hpp:**

```
#ifndef H_FOO
#define H_FOO

namespace Foo
{
    void Start();
}

#endif
```

**foo.cpp:**

```
#include "foo.hpp"

namespace Foo
{
    namespace
    {
        void ProcessStart()
        {
            // ...
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        ProcessStart();
    }
}
```

Only the header file ends up in your public `/include` directory, so nobody will ever know that there are private implementation functions (except perhaps your debugger).

Comment: But the function PrivateStart is not "private" because it has external linkage. It is still accessible.

Comment: Oh sorry I haven't seen the anonymous namespace.

Comment: You know, using `static` there was de-deprecated.

Comment: @Deduplicator: How do you mean? When was it ever deprecated?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions It was deprecated before C++11.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Was any of that ever published?

Comment: Yes. 7.3.1.1 Unnamed namespaces [namespace.unnamed] n1804 contains that. (Oldest draft I could get my hands on. I don't actually have a C++03 standard copy).