# Header-only class + Undefined reference to function ONLY IF returning object of that class

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, linker, undefined-reference

I have a very strange problem with the GCC 5.4.0 linker. I have these files:

[`spline.h`](http://kluge.in-chemnitz.de/opensource/spline/spline.h),
`utils.h/cpp`,
`main.cpp`

`spline.h` is a header-only utility class for fitting points to splines.

1) I create a library with utils.cpp and CMake:

```
add_library(utils_lib utils.cpp)
```

`utils.h` is `#include`ing `spline.h`.

2) I create my binary from `main.cpp`:

```
add_executable(hello_world main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(hello_world utils_lib)
```

3) Inside `utils.cpp`, I have this function:

```
tk::spline fitSpline(const std::vector<double>& x,
                     const std::vector<double>& y)
{
    tk::spline output;
    output.set_points(x,y);
    return output;
}
```

So, if I try to use this function inside `main.cpp`:

```
auto my_spline = fitSpline(x,y);
```

Then I get this linker error:

```
undefined reference to `fitSpline(std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > const&, std::vector<double, std::allocator<double> > const&)'
```

However if I change the return value of `fitSpline` to `double` for example:

```
double fitSpline(const std::vector<double>& x,
                 const std::vector<double>& y)
{
    tk::spline output;
    output.set_points(x,y);

    return 0.0;
}
```

Then I don't get the linker error anymore! It compiles just fine. I really don't understand what the problem is, any hints?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there an existing function signature for `fitSpline` in `utils.h`? Only thing I can think of at the moment. If possible, post the relevant code in `utils.*` and `main.cpp`.

Comment: @hnefatl yes, the signature is there. As I said, if I just change the return value type, everything works just fine.

I just realized that `spline.h` has everything in an anonymous namespace, for sure that must be the reason! Do I need to `#include` it in every cpp file then?

Comment: If they're truly in an [anonymous namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions), then nothing outside the file should be able to access them.
By signature, I meant to ask whether you had a split definition and implementation of the function, and had forgotten to update one of them. Including `spline.h` in `main.cpp` might help, but I can't really work out why it would. Posting more code would help.

Comment: Yes they have the same signature in `utils.cpp` and `utils.h`.

I have just tried `#include`ing `spline.h` everywhere, in `main.cpp`, `utils.cpp` and `utils.h`, but still it doesn't work.

It only works if I skip `utils`, and use `spline.h` inside `main.cpp` directly instead of wrapping it in a function.

Comment: Actually `spline.h` starts with:

// unnamed namespace only because the implementation is in this
// header file and we don't want to export symbols to the obj files
namespace
{

namespace tk
{

(Sorry for formatting, can I do proper code in the comments section?)

Comment: Try commenting out the anonymous namespace - leaving just the `tk` namespace. We do want to export the implementations if we're building to a library, I think. It's just shots in the dark at the moment. RE. formatting, yep just use backticks ` to format it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two translation units. The TU for `utils_lib` and the TU for `main.cpp`.

Names in unnamed namespaces are both in a unique namespace AND effectively have internal linkage (since C++11 they are defined to have internal linkage).

So, trying to reference a type like `tk::spline` from a different TU will fail due to the effective internal linkage.

Duplicating use of `spline.h` would normally be fine, if the objects were stateless and not shared. But here you're not doing that. You are treating them as fungible by creating an object in one TU and trying to store them via a type in a different TU. This will fail because they have different unique namespace names.

If you really don't want to export unnecessary symbols in a header-only library, you should use a internal "detail" namespace for only those symbols, while leaving the ones that should be known to users in the outer namespace.

None of this, btw, has anything to do with `cmake` or any build system. However, since your question uses `cmake` to make the structure much clearer (good job btw), the tag is probably fine.