# Named namespace with internal linkage

Tags: c++, linkage

[@PasserBy has found that my question is a duplicate. The question can be closed, thanks.]

How can I get a named namespace with internal linkage? That is, how can I get a named namespace invisible to external source files? I want this:

```
static namespace N {
    int foo() {return 10;}
    int bar() {return 20;}
}
```

However, unfortunately, C++ does not recognize `static namespace`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unnamed/anonymous namespaces vs. static functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enclose the named namespace within an unnamed namespace:

```
namespace {
    namespace N {
        int foo() {return 10;}
        int bar() {return 20;}
    }
}

int sum()
{
    return N::foo() + N::bar();
}
```

This works because an unnamed namespace automatically exports its members (the sole member in this case being the namespace `N`) to the surrounding scope—without exposing the members to other source files.

Comment: How different is this from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions ?

Comment: @PasserBy Aha. Had not found that one. Sorry for the noise. I'll vote to close my own question.