# Global function recognition failing

Tags: c++, c++11, qtest

When having a simple qtest which compares 2 different objects for a user-defined struct:

```
Test a, b = {1};
QCOMPARE(a, b);
```

Why is there a difference between:

(1)

```
static char* toString(const Test &)
{
    using QTest::toString;
    return toString("Test");
}
```

And

(2)

```
namespace {

char* toString(const Test &)
{
    using QTest::toString;
    return toString("Test");
}

} // unnamed namespace
```

**The first one does call the function when comparing the objects, the second one does not!**

As mentioned [in this conclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154482/2522849), there should be no difference except anonymous namespaces allow you to define translation-unit-local type. Well, here it looks like it's the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `QTest::toString` implementation is a function template:

```
template <class T> char *QTest::toString(const T &value);
```

Specializing this template seems to be one way to provide a custom implementation, but you are using the other one, i.e., adding a function to the `toString` overload set. I haven't looked at the Qt sources, but it seems that the lookup for matching names to construct an overload set is performed using ADL.

Now when you have this

```
struct Test {};

char *toString(const Test&);
```

they are in the same (global) namespace. This works, because using ADL to look for names related to `Test` pulls in the global namespace, and that's where your `toString` overload resides. But that differs from

```
struct Test {};

namespace {
    char *toString(const Test&);
}
```

because the latter is identical to

```
struct Test {};

namespace someRandomUniqueIdentifier {
    char *toString(const Test&);
}

using namespace someRandomUniqueIdentifier;
```

and hence when instantiating a function template for the type `Test`, ADL fails to find the `toString` name as `Test` is not declared in the (unnamed) `someRandomUniqueIdentifier` namespace. If you define `Test` inside the anonymous namespace, the appropriate `toString` function should be invoked.

The thread you linked is about `static` functions vs. anonymous namespaces. The issue you encounter isn't related to that, it's the lookup rules, particularly ADL.

Comment: Yes, I'm not writing a specialized template as I'm using Qt>5.5. Thanks for the explanation.