# const vs static const in anonymous namespace

Tags: c++, qt, static, linker

I want to be able to provide a default name to a class so that I can always have a reasonable name to use when logging errors. I don't need (or want) this name to be a part of the class itself. This default name will never change and so is a good candidate for being `const` or even `constexpr` but you can't do `constexpr QString` or `constexpr std::string` for whatever reason.

In my cpp file, is it better to do

```
namespace {
 const QString NAME("Some Name");
}
```

or

```
namespace {
 static const QString NAME("Some Name");
}
```

I know that both versions will result in `NAME` having internal linkage, but what is best practice? I've seen several discussions on moving global variables to an anonymous namespace but none of them mention using `static` *inside* the namespace.

References:

- http://www.goldsborough.me/c/c++/linker/2016/03/30/19-34-25-internal_and_external_linkage_in_c++/
- [What is external linkage and internal linkage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358400/what-is-external-linkage-and-internal-linkage)
- [Unnamed/anonymous namespaces vs. static functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/297059/static-globals-and-anonymous-namespaces-in-c

Comment: *"but you can't do `constexpr QString` or `constexpr std::string` for whatever reason"* You can't `new` or perform dynamic memory allocation during compilation. This is one of the reasons types like `std::string` don't have `constexpr` constructors. You can have a `constexpr char[]` thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static` is completely redundant in an anonymous namespace. It does *nothing*.

Leave it out since it adds nothing but noise and extra typing in that context. 
Tools like clang-tidy will even generate a warning about it being redundant (depending on options used), so leaving it out also cuts down on noise from tools.