# VS2022 C++20 E3309 an export declaration cannot export a name with internal linkage

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++20, c++-modules

This happens when exporting a module namespace variable. It compiles and works as intended but Intellisense seems disagree. Is it an intellisense bug or a undefined behavior that has side effects?

Tried [Unnamed/anonymous namespaces vs. static functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions) but still same error.

> Env: windows11 VS2022 ISO C++latest with Experimetal Module on.

**employee.ixx**

```cpp
export module employee;

import std.core;

namespace Records {
    //raise E3309
    export const int DefaultRaiseAndDemeritAmount{ 1'000 };
}
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
import std.core;
import employee;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto RaiseModifier = Records::DefaultRaiseAndDemeritAmount;
    //compiler no error and work as intended, print 1000 to console.
    cout << RaiseModifier;
}
```

Comment: I tested the code you posted and there is no error you said, how to reproduce it? When using modules, intellisense often fails, I suggest you report this problem to [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual in these cases, intellisense is incorrect. Well, the rule it cites is correct, but it is applying it where it shouldn't.

Yes, you cannot `export` a name with internal linkage. However, your variable *doesn't* have [internal linkage](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.link#3). The rules for that have an explicit carve-out for "inline or exported" non-template `const`-qualified variables.