# static class real life significance

Tags: c++, oop, class, static

I read a lot on static keyword, I only found static variable, static function, but there is no discussion of static class, can you please explain me about this.

- Why we use static class in c++?
- Why we introduce this type of class?
- Give the physical significance of static class?
- Give the real life example of static class?
- If there is any limitation, then tell me what?

I am waiting for your reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: static class in C++ ?? Also is this homework?

Comment: Is there really some static class in C++?????

Comment: Java has static classes, are you sure it is C++?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321/how-do-you-create-a-static-class-in-c

Comment: Actually these days I learned about OOPS concept, so for that I got familier with all keywords, and this is one of that.

So please explain me.
and this is not a homework.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are no static classes in C++. `static` refers to a storage class, i.e. it applies to objects or functions, not to data types.

In Java, `static class`, when applied to classes that are nested in other classes, means that the nested class can be instantiated independently of any instance of the enclosing class. In C++ that is *always* the case. Nested classes in C++ are always independent data types.

Here is what I mean: First let's take a look at this Java code:

```
public class A {
  public class B {
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    A.B b1 = new A.B();  // <-- This is ill-formed, because A.B is not
                         //     an independent data type

    A a = new A();
    A.B b2 = a.new B();  // <-- This is correct. Use an instance of A to
                         //     create an object of type A.B.
  }
}
```

It defines a class `A`, and a nested class (i.e. a member class, or sub-class) `A.B`. The second line of the main program shows how you **cannot** instantiate a object of type `A.B`. You cannot do this because `B` is a member class of `A` and therefore requires *an existing object of type `A`* to be instantiated. The third line of the main program shows how this is done.

In order to be able to instantiate an object of type `A.B` *directly* (independently of any instance of type `A`) you must make `B` a *static* member class of `A`:

```
public class A {
  public static class B {   // <---- I inserted 'static'
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    A.B b1 = new A.B();  // <-- This is now well-formed

    A a = new A();
    A.B b2 = a.new B();  // <-- This is now ill-formed.
  }
}
```

**On the other hand, in C++** this is not required, because in C++ a member class is always an independent data type (in the sense that no instance of the enclosing class is required to be able to create instances of the nested class):

```
class A
{
public:
  class B
  {
  };
};

int main()
{
  A::B b;   // <--- Perfectly well-formed instantiation of A::B
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate this term for java.

Comment: @jham I think I had edited my answer already when you submitted your comment. Is the relation to Java _static classes_ clear now?

Comment: I didn't understand these, If you explain me by usng above question that comes in my mind, then it will be good for me for better understanding

Comment: thnanks a lot, jogojapan. superb explanation. I like that.