# Can we have a static class in C++?

Tags: c++

I was just wondering whether we can have static classes in C++. What I mean is can we declare a class as static in C++ like `static class foo`? I know we can have static member variables and static member functions in C++ but I am not sure about static classes.

Edit:

I intended to ask what does it mean for a class to be static.

Comment: What would it mean, in your view, for a class to be static?

Comment: Are you looking for a singleton?

Comment: Is something like a [namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace_%28computer_science%29#C.2B.2B) what you're looking for?

Comment: Damn close to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12436511/static-class-real-life-significance

Comment: Its actually my bad for the question being unclear (I guess that's why its down-voted). I was actually looking for what does it mean for a class to be static. I know that static variables can only be instantiated once. The same goes for static methods and they do not belong to a particular instance of a class. I'll try yo be more clear and specific next time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The static keyword implies that the object that it refers to exists through the life of the entire program.  A class definition is just an outline for constructing an object.

With that in mind, perhaps you might be looking to do something like create a namespace or create a [singleton object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), a class that is designed to only ever have a single instance.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was precisely looking for. :)

Answer (score 9):

`static` is a *storage class* specifier.

- Applied to variables, it specifies the object's *lifetime* and *visibility* -- in this case, the lifetime is the entire program's execution, and the visibility is restricted to the particular *translation unit* (usually a given source file).
- Applied to functions, it similarly specifies the object's *visbility* -- limited to the particular translation unit in which it is defined.
- Applied to class members variables and functions, it defines the variable to be a property of the class, and not the object itself.

So that's the semi-pedantic definition.  The question is, what semantics exactly would you like to attach to the idea of a "static class"?  Nested classes automatically have static-like properties -- they are a property of the class, and not the individual object.  If you wanted static-like properties for a class declared in an outer scope (i.e. not conflicting with the one-definition rule across different translation units), you can use an [anonymous namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions).

Comment: i can see two things wrong with that statement.  first, a function is not "storage", but it can be static.  second, some things take up space without being storage.

Comment: this begs the question... who are the 5 people who upvoted that statement?

Comment: @thang: eh, fine.  Edited for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can basically achieve nearly the same if you create a class with static methods (and data) only. Beware thought, there is no static constructor concept in C++.

Comment: You would also want to make the constructor `private`.

Answer (score 1):

If by "static class" you are referring to the ones in C#, then the equivalent in C++ is to just make a single constructor and make it private, and avoid making non-static members.

If by "static class" you are referring to the ones in Java, then *all* C++ classes are "static", so you can't add "static" because it would be redundant.