# C++ classes vs functions, reference parameter in constructor

Tags: c++, function, class, reference, constructor

Coming from a language that didn't have any classes (program flow was controlled using only functions), I'm curious about when to utilise a class in C++ versus when to just use a function. Also I have a specific question about memory allocation when using a reference in a class constructor. For the code:

```
void add1_func(int &x){
        x=x+1;
}

class add1_class{
        private:
        void add1(int &x){
        x=x+1;
        }

        public:
        add1_class(int &x){
                    add1(x);
        }
};


int main(){
        int x=2;
        add1_func(x);
        add1_class foo(x);
        return 0;
}
```

Both the function and class route clearly achieve the same thing here. Is either one considered better practice, or is it just a matter of preference? The function would probably be better in this simple case, but if the class contained a bunch of other private functions I wanted to group together, it might be better to put them in a class.

Second part of the question: are the two methods equivalent in terms of memory usage? I know that when you declare a variable like

```
Type t;
```

then memory is allocated, however much memory "Type" needs for the instance 't'. But because I used a reference in the class constructor (is that ok?), when I declared foo, did that actually allocate any memory?

Comment: classes are nouns, functions are verbs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first question is far too broad to be answered here. Try finding a book on object orientated programming.

`add1_class` is a waste of time. It's only a complicated way of calling a function. You might as well just call a function. Generally speaking classes are only useful when they have some *state*, i.e. some data members.

I would expect an `add1_class` variable to occupy some memory (1 byte perhaps). Because even though it has no data members, it would be legal to take the address of an `add1_class` variable, so it has to 'live' somewhere. Maybe a compiler would be capable of optimising that away, but maybe not.

Comment: Just to add emphasis on the optimization point: I would be shocked if it both scenarios didn't optimize into the same thing so long as you don't treat the class as an object (take addr of it, store it, etc)

Answer (score 1):

When to make it a member function: When the function is logically coupled with the class when the function needs to access private or protected members, it's better to make it a member than a friend.

When to make it a free function: When it's a generic function that can be templatized to naturally work on other classes. You cannot access private members of the class from a standalone function.

Many a times, you are required to keep few things private, so that the user cannot edit them from outside the class definition. This is more common when you templatize a class.

Answer (score 1):

For me the answer is state. If you need to or if it helps to store the state after a function call then a Class is what you want.

In your example you do not need a class because you have no state you need to store.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not any object with some state, using a function would be the preferred way. If you need to implement a set of similar methods that do not have any state, you can think of encapsulating them in a class with only static methods or declaring them in a namespace. If that is what you need, take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/112451/1765897), discussing these options.