# Compiling error for a class with static members in C++

Tags: class, c++11, static

I created a `class` with `static` members but I faced a compiling error which is **"a storage class can only be specified for objects and functions."**.

What's the solution?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

static class Hi {

    public: static string ShowMessage(string Message)
    {
        return Message;
    }
};

int main()
{
    cout << Hi::ShowMessage("Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "`static class`" ?

Comment: I think this can help :
[Can I write something like `static class`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31201984/13007571)

Comment: Some other languages do not allow namespaces to contain code or data, only types, and end up using `static class` as a workaround for this limitation.  C++ namespaces *can* have function and data members, and are what you are looking for here.  (C++ does still end up using non-instantiable classes to workaround *other* limitations, like that fact that a namespace cannot have template arguments and a class can)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "static class" in C++.

You can have a `static` member or a `static` method (as your `ShowMessage()`) inside a `class` or a `struct`.

You can also have a `static` object that instantiate a `class`/`struct`.

But there isn't a `static class`

Answer (score 1):

There is no `static` specifier for class in C++. A class can be `final or abstract` but not static. So this will give syntax error.

Comment: I see. But could you tell me shortly what are final and abstract classes in C++?